# how to solve 403 - Forbidden in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

hello everyone i have a site like https://www.example.com/blog
problem is that when i open my wordpress blog shows following error :
403 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory or you do not have enough permissions to access the resource

[image]

Comment: only blog or all subpages?

Comment: See this link https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-403-forbidden-error-in-wordpress/ it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

403 forbidden issue solved: it is because of the .htaccess corrupted file.
How?

1. Downloaded the .htaccess from Cpanel (public_html) to have a backup of it.
   and then, delete the file.
2. Generate a fresh .htaccess file, by login to the WordPress dashboard, and click on Settings › Permalinks.

3)Without making any changed, click on the save changes button at the bottom of the page.

and it will generate a fresh .htaccess file for you

And refresh the site, the issue will be fixed.